# MudBlazor - how to make the input remember the values

Tags: .net, razor, mudblazor

I have a following component with input (MudTextField):

```
<div class="parcel-top-row">
    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Disabled="true">
        @L10n["Label"]
    </MudButton>
    <MudItem xs="12" sm="6">
        <MudTextField
            OnlyValidateIfDirty="true"
            @bind-Value="Id"
            OnBlur="FetchSth"
            Variant="Variant.Outlined"
            AutoFocus="true"
            />
     
    </MudItem>
    <MudButton
        Variant="Variant.Outlined"
        OnClick="FetchSth"
        ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit"
    >
        @L10n["Button"]
    </MudButton>
</div>
```

How do I make this input remember the history of inserted values? So if I've submitted `XXX` next time I'll get an autocomplete with `XXX`.

I've tried to use:

```
<MudTextField UserAttributes=@InputAttributes T="string" InputType="InputType.Text" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />

@code {
    private Dictionary<string, object> InputAttributes { get; set; } =
        new Dictionary<string, object>() 
            {
               { "autocomplete", "on" },
            };
}
```

but it doesn't really work.
I'm testing it on Edge, but Chrome doesn't work either.